# Ошибки С3646 и C4430

Tags: c++

Есть у меня заголовочный файл (Prog.h):

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include <Setupapi.h>
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#include <Uxtheme.h>

#include "Res_micro.h"
#include "Connect.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Setupapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "UxTheme.lib")

#define wWidth          0x1F4
#define wHeight         0x190

#define TAB_DEV         0x0
#define TAB_MICRO       0x1
#define TAB_MEM         0x2
#define TAB_FUSE        0x3

#define START_YES       0x1
#define START_NO        0x2

typedef struct _PROG_SET
{
     MICRO_INFO def_micro;
     FT_INFO ft_info;
     HANDLE hDevice;
     HWND hDlg;
     BOOL Connected;
} PROG_SET, *LPPROG_SET;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

Соответственно, в этом файле подключаются еще два файла Res_micro.h и Connect.h
Содержание Res_micro.h:

```
#pragma once

#define SIZE_STR        0x15
#define SIZE_STR_EX     0x32
#define SIZE_STR_VOLT   0x50

typedef struct _MICRO_FUSE
{
    TCHAR FuseHightByte[0x8][SIZE_STR];
    TCHAR FuseLowByte[0x8][SIZE_STR];
    TCHAR FuseLockByte[0x8][SIZE_STR];
    TCHAR FuseExtendedByte[0x8][SIZE_STR];
} MICRO_FUSE, *LPMICRO_FUSE;

typedef struct _MICRO_INFO
{
     MICRO_FUSE micro_fuse;
     TCHAR Name[SIZE_STR];
     TCHAR SizeFlash[SIZE_STR];
     TCHAR SizeEeprom[SIZE_STR];
     TCHAR Voltage[SIZE_STR_VOLT];
     TCHAR MaxFrequency[SIZE_STR];
     TCHAR Corps[SIZE_STR_EX];
     DWORD NumMicros;
     BYTE AtmelSign;
     BYTE FlashSign;
     BYTE MicroSign;
 } MICRO_INFO, *LPMICRO_INFO;

 LPMICRO_INFO WINAPI GetStartAddrMicros();
 BOOL WINAPI EnumResMicro(HWND hWnd);
 LPMICRO_INFO WINAPI SetSettingsMicro(HWND hWnd, TCHAR *sMicro);
```

И содержание файла Connect.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "Prog.h"

#define FT_SP_300               0x12C
#define FT_SP_600               0x258
#define FT_SP_1200              0x4B0
#define FT_SP_2400              0x960
#define FT_SP_4800              0x12C0
#define FT_SP_9600              0x2580
#define FT_SP_14400             0x3840
#define FT_SP_19200             0x4B00
#define FT_SP_28800             0x7080
#define FT_SP_38400             0x9600
#define FT_SP_56000             0xDAC0
#define FT_SP_57600             0xE100
#define FT_SP_115200            0x1C200
#define FT_SP_128000            0x1F400
#define FT_SP_230400            0x38400
#define FT_SP_256000            0x3E800
#define FT_SP_460800            0x70800
#define FT_SP_921600            0xE1000

#define FT_BITS_8               (UCHAR) 0x8
#define FT_BITS_7               (UCHAR) 0x7

#define FT_STOP_BITS_1          (UCHAR) 0x0
#define FT_STOP_BITS_2          (UCHAR) 0x2

#define FT_PARITY_NONE          (UCHAR) 0x0
#define FT_PARITY_ODD           (UCHAR) 0x1
#define FT_PARITY_EVEN          (UCHAR) 0x2
#define FT_PARITY_MARK          (UCHAR) 0x3
#define FT_PARITY_SPACE         (UCHAR) 0x4

typedef struct _FT_INFO
{
   ULONG Type;
   TCHAR SirialNumder[0x10];
   TCHAR Description[0x40];
} FT_INFO, *LPFT_INFO;

typedef struct _FT_SET
{
    DWORD Speed;
    DWORD tRead;
    DWORD tWrite;
    UCHAR Bytes;
    UCHAR Parity;
    UCHAR StopBytes;
 } FT_SET, *LPFT_SET;

 BOOL WINAPI GetDeviceInfo(HANDLE hDevice, PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA_A dev_data, LPBOOL lpDevInfo, LPFT_INFO lpFT_Info);
 HANDLE WINAPI OpenDevice(DWORD dwDevice, LPFT_INFO lpFT_Info, LPBOOL GetInfo);
 BOOL WINAPI ResetDevice(HANDLE hDevice);
 BOOL WINAPI SetDeviceSet(HANDLE hDevice, LPFT_SET lpFT_Set);
```

Не могу понять, в чем у меня проблема. При сборке проекта, компилятор MSVC выдает две ошибки:

```
d:\programing\vs\projects\prog\prog\prog.h(33): error C3646: ft_info: неизвестный спецификатор переопределения (компилируется исходный файл Connect.cpp)
d:\programing\vs\projects\prog\prog\prog.h(33): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию (компилируется исходный файл Connect.cpp)
```

Почему он ругается именно на структуру FT_INFO? Что с ней не так? Тогда, почему же он не ругается на MICRO_INFO?

Answer (score 3):

Проблема состоит в том, что вы включаете заголовок `"Prog.h"`  в заголовок `"Connect.h"`, а заголовок `"Connect.h"`  в заголовок `"Prog.h"`.

Из-за этого компилятор запутался и считает, что структура `FT_INFO` еще не определена в месте определения `PROG_SET`

Возможно, если удаление заголовка `"Prog.h"` из заголовка `"Connect.h"` будет безболезненным для других объявлений, то код будет компилироваться. Иначе вам надо разбираться с перекрестными ссылками в двух заголовках.